# How to access integer named attribute from pyspark row?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For the row object defined as

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
rr=Row('a',3)
r = rr(3,4)
print(r)
output:
Row(a=3, 3=4)
```

I can access the value of `a` as either `r.a` or `r['a']`

But neither can be used to access the value of the key 3. How can I access the value of a Row attribute if it is named by an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract it by using its position within the row. So in your case, that would be the value at index 1:

```py
>>> r[1]
4
```

Or, if you don't know the position on beforehand, and just want to index using the column name `3` you could do something like this:

```py
# Grabbing index of column with 3 as name
>>> wantedIndex = r.__fields__.index(3)
>>> r[wantedIndex]
4
```